# How to Sort 2 Element Tuple of Strings in Mixed Order Using key Parameter (Not cmp)

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

In Python, I have something like the following (although randomly shuffled):

```
l = [('a', 'x'),
     ('a', 'y'),
     ('a', 'z'),
     ('b', 'x'),
     ('b', 'y'),
     ('b', 'z'),
    ]
```

If I call `sorted(l)`, I get a sorted result (like above) which is what one would expect. However, what I need is to forward sort on the *first* element of the tuple and reverse sort on the *second* element. In other words, I would like the following result:

```
l = [('a', 'z'),
     ('a', 'y'),
     ('a', 'x'),
     ('b', 'z'),
     ('b', 'y'),
     ('b', 'x'),
    ]
```

In Python2.x, there exists a `cmp` parameter that can be passed to `sorted()` to achieve this result, but Python3 no longer has this. It has only a `key` parameter. Is there any way to achieve the desired sort order using only the `key` parameter?

I know I can define a whole new class to wrap my tuples, or use something like `functools.cmp_to_key` (which also creates a wrapper class), but that all seems heavy handed for such a simple operation. Is there no other recourse?

edit: I should add that the strings won't all be one-character strings and that, in some cases, the list of tuples contain non-string data [i.e. (basestring, datetime)].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorting in Python is [stable](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) as of Python 2.2.

So, you can sort by the **second** value first with the **reverse** flag on:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
>>> l
[('a', 'z'), ('b', 'z'), ('a', 'y'), ('b', 'y'), ('a', 'x'), ('b', 'x')]
```

Then you can sort by the **first** value:

```
>>> l.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
>>> l
[('a', 'z'), ('a', 'y'), ('a', 'x'), ('b', 'z'), ('b', 'y'), ('b', 'x')]
```

Answer (score 3):

In a single step:

```
>>> l.sort(key=lambda t: (t[0], -ord(t[1])))
>>> l
[('a', 'z'), ('a', 'y'), ('a', 'x'), ('b', 'z'), ('b', 'y'), ('b', 'x')]
```

Any time you need to sort on multiple keys you can make your key function a tuple since tuples are compared lexicographically.  If you need to reverse sort on one of the keys just make that element negative.  Obviously you can't just make the string negative so you first need to convert it to an integer with `ord`.

Comment: Only in school are sort keys 1 byte wide.

Answer (score 2):

The [Python Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html) recommends that you take advantage of [sort stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) and do the sort in two passes:

```
>>> l.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)   # SECONDARY KEY: field 1 descending
>>> l.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])                 # PRIMARY KEY:   field 0 ascending
>>> l
[('a', 'z'), ('a', 'y'), ('a', 'x'), ('b', 'z'), ('b', 'y'), ('b', 'x')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by running sorted twice on the list, first using a reverse sort with the second item in each tuple, then using a normal sort on the newly sorted list with the first item in each tuple.

```
l = [('a', 'y'),
     ('a', 'x'),
     ('b', 'y'),
     ('b', 'x'),
     ('b', 'z'),
     ('a', 'z'),
    ]
l = sorted(l, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
l = sorted(l, key=lambda tup: tup[0])
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
l = sorted(sorted(l, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True),
           key=lambda tup: tup[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [('a', 'x'),
 ('a', 'y'),
 ('a', 'z'),
 ('b', 'x'),
 ('b', 'y'),
 ('b', 'z'),
]

>>> sorted(l, key = lambda x: 2*abs(ord(x[0])-ord('a')) + abs(ord(x[1])-ord('z')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Only in school are sort keys 1 byte wide.

Comment: @JohnMachin: could you please expand on that. I really don't know what you mean

Comment: It was a snarky response (and an incomplete question on my part) but ord() only works on single characters. The code I am working on actually has multicharacter strings as well as some non-string data.

Comment: @davemankoff: Edit your question to add the new information. "as well as some non-string data" could be a problem in 3.X. Are you are mixing different types in either or both keys? Note carefully what happens when you do `a = ['foo', 42]; a.sort()` in 3.X.

Comment: @JohnMachin we're not mixing data-types directly, thankfully. In one of our cases, the tuples are (basestring, datetime), which ord() obviously doesn't work with.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: -1 not because of the one-byte wide thingy but because (1) your "sorted" line is missing TWO right parentheses (2) your gimmicky expression to return an int instead of a tuple fails; that weight of 2 on the first element should be at least 26 (if the input is restricted to lowercase ASCII letters). Try sorting az, bz, aa